# SQL Server 2012 Unattended Installation

Tags: cmd, installation, sql-server-2012-express, unattended-processing

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express from command line. Here is a test example:

```
setup.exe /QS /ACTION=install /INSTANCENAME="UnattendedCmd123" 
          /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SQLENGINE,SSMS 
          /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTINADMINISTRATORS"
```

This should work but it doesn't install (no error) I checked the summary in the logs and it shows:

User Input Settings:

```
  ACTION:                        RunRules
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  ENU:                           true
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, SSMS
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCENAME:                  UNATTENDEDCMD123
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   true
  RULES:                         GlobalRules
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  X86:                           false

IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  false
```

Why is it coming through as false when I clearly have the parameter?

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a solution to this? I have a similar issue where it seems like its just ignoring my `/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS` command.

Comment: @Hershizer33 yeah but I don't remember the solution. I think I read somewhere else that its always false, and when I dug into it it was failing for another reason unrelated to accepting the terms.